# PECL_HTTP not recognised php ubuntu

Tags: php, httprequest

I am trying to use the HttpRequest class which should be in the PECL_HTTP extension of php.
I have php5 and used the following to install pecl_http.

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http

pecl/pecl_http is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.0.1
install failed
```

After that i enter into my php.ini:

```
[PHP]
extension=http.so
[...]
```

Then i restart my apache2 server, and try using the HttpRequest class, but it gives me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found
```

What are possible error's i might have missed?

**UPDATE**: (Changed the title)

The Extension is not shown in phpinfo(), i set

```
extension=http.so
```

And checked if the `http.so` file is in my `extension_dir`. I really don't know how to make php recognise the extension.

**UPDATE 2**:
I managed to install extension, but the class still does not exist.
For others, i had to reference the other extensions pecl_http needs. (For me: `propro.so`, `raphfr.so`)

**UPDATE 3**:
I did not manage to make the Class visible, the answers below show some approaches with other classes.

***I solved this issue by using CURL.***

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show the module as enabled?

Comment: No, it does not. And i really don't know why. See Update

Comment: Did you update the correct php.ini file?

Comment: I modified the php.ini file that is mentioned in phpinfo() as "Loaded Configuration File"

Comment: what does the apache log say?

Comment: Where does the apache2 server come from? A ppa?

Comment: Geeo: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found, was copied from the apache error.log.
Darsstar: I just got it with apt-get install apache2 on Ubuntu

Comment: I think Geeo was asking what the error_log states AT STARTUP WHEN PHP TRIES TO LOAD IT'S EXTENSIONS

Comment: See Update. (I did not get any errors at startup... :( )

Answer (score 4):

You have installed the new version of the extension which uses a completely different API. I still don't know how it works, but I will update my answer one I know. The Documentation of the new version is to be found at http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http.

To Install the old version, first uninstall the new verion and then execute

```
pecl install http://pecl.php.net/get/pecl_http-1.7.6.tgz
```

UPDATE: here are two examples from the documentation, both should work well:

one request (can be found at http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Client/enqueue):

```
<?php
(new http\Client)->enqueue(new http\Client\Request("GET", "http://php.net"), 
    function(http\Client\Response $res) {
        printf("%s returned %d\n", $res->getTransferInfo("effective_url"), $res->getResponseCode());
        return true; // dequeue
})->send();
```

multiple requests (can be found at http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Client/once):

```
<?php
$client = new http\Client;
$client->enqueue(new http\Client\Request("HEAD", "http://php.net"));
$client->enqueue(new http\Client\Request("HEAD", "http://pecl.php.net"));
$client->enqueue(new http\Client\Request("HEAD", "http://pear.php.net"));

printf("Transfers ongoing");
while ($client->once()) {
    // do something else here while the network transfers are busy
    printf(".");
    // and then call http\Client::wait() to wait for new input
    $client->wait();
}
printf("\n");

while ($res = $client->getResponse()) {
    printf("%s returned %d\n", $res->getTransferInfo("effective_url"),
        $res->getResponseCode());
}
```

In both examples you can use `$res->getBody()` to return the body of the response.

I couldn't test these examples but I have heard of other people that they work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by arrange the order in wich extensions are loaded in php.ini

All my other extensions was loaded using their own .ini files in `/etc/php5/mods_available`.
In my apache2 `error.log` I noticed that `json_decode` was needed by `http.so` to load.

I created a file for http (http.ini) and a symlink in  `/etc/php5/apache/conf.d` with a higher prefix than json.

my http.ini

---

```
; configuration for php http module
; priority=50

extension=raphf.so

extension=propro.so

extension=http.so
```

---

use the new pecl_http.2.0.6 like this

```
new http\Message();
```

or extend in your own class as extends http\Message