# osx 10.9 php 5.4 pecl_http - class HttpRequest not found

Tags: pecl

I am running php 5.4.17 on OS X 10.9.1.
I have installed pear using this command:

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

Then I have installed pecl_http with:

```
pecl install pecl_http
```

I have added extension lines to my php.ini and add 'x' permission to library binaries. If I run php -i I get:

```
http

HTTP Support => enabled
Extension Version => 2.0.4

Used Library => Compiled => Linked
libz => 1.2.5 => 1.2.5
libcurl => 7.30.0 => 7.30.0
libevent => disabled => disabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
http.etag.mode => crc32b => crc32b
```

But if I try to run php script with HttpRequest inside I still get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found
```

Can somebody give me a clue what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `pecl_http 2.0.4` and probably refer to documentation from `http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php` which is for older version. There is a post that's already explained your problem:
[PECL_HTTP not recognised php ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228088/pecl-http-not-recognised-php-ubuntu)

In fact, you should refer to the documentation defined here:
http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http

To verify: `if (class_exists('http\Client\Request')) printf 'pecl_http v2 is installed'`